# How to start the video in iPad from where it was stopped earlier?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, xcode4.3

I'm playing a video in iPad and stopping it using "Home" button on iPad. When i again start the video it should start from where it was stopped earlier and not from beginning. Can anyone tell me how do i do this?

To restart the video from beginning i used

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
    {
       NSLog(@"app enter foreground");
       PlayVideo *PVC=[[PlayVideo alloc] initWithNibName:@"PlayVideo" bundle:nil];
       self.window.rootViewController=PVC;     
    }
```

Comment: Are you overriding Home Button action? That could lead your app getting rejected.

Comment: no i'm overriding "AppDelegate" method, to restart the app. But i want it to begin from where it was stopped.

Comment: When you put app in background just pause the video and play it again when you come back.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to listen the state change of videoplayer.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
selector:@selector(playbackStateChanged) 
name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

In the applicationDidEnterBackground, capture the playback time. MPMoviePlayerController conforms to the MPMediaPlayback protocol, and does have a currentPlaybackTime property available.
 Save this playback in the NSUserDefaults or wherever u feel easy, for the next launch of app, i.e. in applicationDidiEnterForeground method resume playing from this playback time.

Comment: @Ankita: Did u got the result or not.. if yes do the favor of accepting the answer.

Comment: i used applicationWillEnterForeground delegate method to resolve the issue.Therefore i did not try the method suggested by you, i shall try it let you know.Thnks